# Microsoft Outlook Sender's IP Address

Tags: email, outlook, ip

I have been looking through email headers and I've noticed the sender's IP address is visible with email sent with Microsoft Outlook.

Particularly in the "Received" header. Ex:

```
Received: from -redacted hostname- (c-redactedipaddress-.hsd1.ca.comcast.net. [-redactedipaddress-]) by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id -redacted- for <multiple recipients> (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128); Thu, 30 Oct 2014 15:32:04 -0700 (PDT)
```

This is only one example of many emails I have. While not important, wouldn't this be considered a type of security issue?

Answer (score 0):

These are just MIME headers added by the sending mail client or the mail server. This is actually security feature, not security problem. Do you not have the right to know who exactly sent you an email?